# How to reverse a given array of numbers in Python 3?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, data-structures

For example:

I have an array number like

```
n = int(input().strip())           # 4
arr = map(int,input().strip().split(' ')) #2 4 3 1
print(arr[::-1])
```

inputs:

```
4 
2 4 3 1
```

My output is `[1,3,4,2]`

But actual output must be `1 3 4 2`

How do I implement this using python 3?

Comment: You question isn't about reversing a list, it's about providing a string output for a list.

Comment: just `print(*arr[::-1])`, as chepner said, it's the outputting that your question's about.

Comment: Also, the output of `map` isn't sliceable in Python 3, so your code doesn't produce the output you claim it does.

Answer (score 1):

You could re-join the list to a string:

```
print(" ".join([str(x) for x in arr]))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just unpack list using * operator

```
>>> arr = [*range(5)]
>>> print(*arr)
0 1 2 3 4
```